# ¿Cómo puedo condicionar el cambio de estado de una orden usando el total de la orden?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy usando un metodo de pago llamado account funds, necesito validar que el usuario no exceda su monto asignado.

Por ahora solo puedo mostrar una alerta al momento de actualizar o recalcular el pedido. Esto es en el lado del admin al momento de editar una orden.

```
<?php
    self::remove_order_total_filter_adjustment();
    $funds = get_user_meta($order->get_user_id() , 'account_funds', true);
    echo wc_price($funds);
    self::add_order_total_filter_adjustment();
?>

<?
$monto_compra = $order->get_total();
  if ($funds < $monto_compra) {
  $funds2 = number_format($funds, 0, ',', '.');
?>

<script>
alert("Los fondos no alcanzan, tu pedido no sera procesado. Maximo permitido: <?php echo '$'.$funds2.'.-';?>");
</script>

<?php  }; ?>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Traduce tu pregunta al español o si no, será cerrada por la comunidad. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hola ya he editado la pregunta a español. Muchas gracias.